# Grafana - How to set a default field value for a visualization with a cloudwatch query as the data source

Tags: grafana

I'm new to grafana, so I might be missing something obvious.  But, I have a custom cloudwatch metric that records http response codes into buckets (e.g. 2xx, 3xx, etc.).

My grafana visualization is using a query to pull and group data from cloudwatch and the resulting fields are dynamic: 2xx (us-east-1), 2xx (us-west-1), 3xx (us-east-1), etc.

I then use transformations to aggregate those values for a global view of the data:
[image]

The problem is, I can't create the transformation until the data exists.  I'd like to have a 5xx field, but since that data is sporadic, it doesn't show up in the UI and I can't find a way to force "5xx (...)" to exist and have it get used when/if those response codes start occurring.

Is there a way to create placeholder fields somehow to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create it in the UI. But you have still option to edit that in the panel model directly. It is JSON, which represent whole panel. Edit it manually - in the panel menu click Inspect > Panel JSON and create&customize another item in the transformation section. It is not very convenient option to edit panel, but you will achieve your target.

Comment: perfect.  didn't know that was possible.  thanks!